# How to specify an artifact in help:effective-pom?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am trying to use
`mvn help:effective-pom -Dartifact=com.group:artifactname:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` but it is still printing out effective pom for a current project.

Is there any way to use it? I am following [Maven help:effective-pom documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html).

Comment: have you tried `-f,--file <arg>                        Force the use of an alternate POM
                                        file (or directory with pom.xml).`

Comment: Try adding `-X` to your execution to get verbose output. Might be worth redirecting the output to a file, because I would expect it to be lenghty, and any relevant information (such as the artifact not being found) to be found in the first few lines.

Answer (score 4):

This parameter is recent : it requires at least the `3.0.0` version of `maven-help-plugin`.
Your pom.xml doesn't use it very probably.
Note that you don't have any error in the output because a user property (`-D`) may be used to define a plugin parameter or any custom property.  So the plugin just doesn't use it if it is not recognized.

So configure your pom to use a `maven-help-plugin` version that supports it or the last :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
<build>
```

or specify explicitly the version of the plugin in the command line :

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:effective-pom -Dartifact=com.group:artifactname:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: I have tried that as well (that was the first thing that came to my mind) without any success - it's still printing out the effective pom of the project instead of specific artifact, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dawid Pura It works very well. I just tested the command. Could you test with a specific library ? For example : `com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre` such as `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:effective-pom -Dartifact=com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre`

Comment: You probably test with an artifact that depends on the current project.