# How to prevent Unknown packaging "bundle" error when computing the effective POM

Tags: maven, bundle, effective-pom

I am reading an effective POM from the command line (using the approach described here: [How to specify an artifact in help:effective-pom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982202/how-to-specify-an-artifact-in-helpeffective-pom))

For the artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.scala-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-logging_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Using the command:

```
mvn help:effective-pom -Dartifact=com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:3.7.2
```

I get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< mvntmp:mvntmp >----------------------------
[INFO] Building mvntmp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:effective-pom (default-cli) @ mvntmp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.540 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-20T15:26:34+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:effective-pom (default-cli) on project mvntmp: Unable to get the POM for the artifact 'com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:3.7.2'. Verify the artifact parameter.: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] [ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 6, column 16: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:3.7.2
[ERROR] [ERROR] Unknown packaging: bundle @ line 6, column 16
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: The given dependency is not a `jar` it's a `bundle` packaging type... https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.typesafe.scala-logging/scala-logging_2.12/3.7.2/bundle

Comment: Yes but I can probably make maven aware of this new packaging type.

Comment: and what the difference between a jar packaging and a bundle packaging type ?